# Spring java based configuration refuses to work

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have a spring mvc application in which I use a configuration like this :

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver() {//
        CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver =
                new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieName("locale");
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("ru"));
        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }
}
```

I remote connect to tomcat debug jwm with a break point, and see if the bean is initialized and the break point is actually being passed. So the bean is initalized. However it does not do what I want it to do. But If I use this :

```
<bean id="localeResolver"  
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="cookieName" value="locale"/>
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>
```

in applicationContext.xml, it just works fine. I also use this in applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
```

Why do you think the java based configuration does not work but the xml does?

Note :

All the other java based config work except, CookieLocaleResolver and ResourceBundleMessageSource.

Comment: Rename your method to `localeResolver` instead of `cookieLocaleResolver`. A `LocaleResolver` is detected by the magic name `localeResolver` if that doesn't exist the default is used. When using java config the method is, by default, used as the bean id.

Comment: I found out that was the problem. However, if you would post the answer, I would like to accept it, as you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring MVC a `LocaleResolver` is detected by the name/id of the bean, for this the magic name `localeResolver` is used (see the [`DispatcherServlet`s javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html)). In XML the id of your bean matches this.

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver() { ... }

}
```

When using java config the method is, by default, used as the bean id. So in your case you get a bean with id `cookieLocaleResolver`.

To fix this simply rename your method to `localeResolver` instead of `cookieLocaleResolver`.

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() { ... }

}
```

Another solution would be to specify the `name` attribute of the `@Bean` annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfiguration {

    @Bean(name={"localeResolver"})
    public CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver() { ... }

}
```